# How to redirect a folder to another website in nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

Ubuntu 16.04
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1

I'm trying to redirect traffic from the /dealers folder to a new website like so

`https://www.domain.tld/dealers/aff.php?aff=8 => https://fqdn.domain.tld/aff.php?aff=8`

In my Nginx file, I have tried various combinations with no success...

```
location /dealers/ {
  return 301 https://fqdn.domain.tld/$1;
}

location /dealers/ {
  return 301 https://fqdn.domain.tld$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
location ^~ /dealers/ {
    rewrite ^/dealers(.+)$ https://fqdn.domain.tld$1 permanent;
}
```

I recommend to test redirects without `permanent` flag, and add it only after you're 100% sure that all redirects are correct.

Comment: Almost. It carries the /dealers folder to the destination website. I need to drop the dealer's folder.

Comment: It would not. I guess your browser cached redirects (because they were permanent) and now you have to clean cache. Or check with `curl`/`wget`.

Comment: Oh, 404. I guess there is usual `location` for php. I’ve fixed answer

Comment: Well, it works via curl but none of my redirects work via the browser. I do have a proxy in front of the webserver. I have your work and the other redirects that are not working on the webserver. Do I need to transfer them to the proxy nginx configs?